# Video file not running

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I was trying to run this code to play a video file in my project. However, I get the following error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" . Any idea why?

```
import AVKit
import SwiftUI

struct HelpView: View {
    private let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "tutorial", ofType: "mp4")!))
   var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
                           .onAppear() {
                               player.play()
                           }
     }
}
```

Comment: Try checking out of your resource path is getting correct or not, as I can you that is the only one which you are trying to force unwrapping which can leads to a crash

Comment: @Jayachandra what do you mean? I have the video file in my swift project. And the project runs sweet with no error. However, when I click the help button to go to the HelpView, I get a crash.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Its working now. I just needed to add it to my targets.